# crontab to run bash script if not running already

Tags: python, bash, cron

I am trying to run python script from bash script via crontab but somehow it isn't running as expected.

run_scripts.py

```
import subprocess

program_list = ["phone_search.py", "benefit_id_search.py"]

for program in program_list:
    subprocess.call(["python", program])
    print("Finished:" + program)
```

cron.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo "$PWD"
pid_file='/root/pipedrive_CRM/run_scripts.pid'
if [ ! -s "$pid_file" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat $pid_file) > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo $$ > "$pid_file"
  exec /root/pipedrive_CRM/venv/bin/python /root/pipedrive_CRM/run_scripts.py
fi
```

crontab

```
52 21 * * * /root/pipedrive_CRM/cron.sh
```

I tried to run bash script manually it is running fine as well as python script but when I try to run with crontab it isn't working. Any idea what seems to be the issue here? Either python script or shell script? Thanks

Here is tracing output on manual run `./cron.sh`:

```
+ echo /root/pipedrive_CRM
/root/pipedrive_CRM
+ pid_file=/root/pipedrive_CRM/run_scripts.pid
+ '[' '!' -s /root/pipedrive_CRM/run_scripts.pid ']'
++ cat /root/pipedrive_CRM/run_scripts.pid
+ kill -0 733932
+ echo 734004
+ exec /root/pipedrive_CRM/venv/bin/python /root/pipedrive_CRM/run_scripts.py
```

Comment: is the file executable for root ? What happens when you write `bash -c "/root/pipedrive_CRM/cron.sh"` in your crontab ?

Comment: _somehow it isn't running_ : Could you make this somehow more specific? For instance, is the bash script at least started?

Comment: Ill make a bet and say that the issue is that your python script "run_scripts.py" does not find the scripts in program_list because of "cwd" is not set ..

Comment: @user1934428 Yes script get started and generate `run_scripts.pid` file and that is it after that nothing happens.

Comment: Not even error message? In this case, turn on tracing (using `set -x`) and post here the output of the trace.

Comment: @user1934428 where to write `set -x` I mean in crontab or in the bash script? Sorry I am new to cronjobs.

Comment: `-x` is unrelated to cron jobs. It is a bash option which turns on tracing. The trace is written to stderr. Reasonably I would write it at the first command after the #! line. And while you are at it, you can also (for the safe side) add a `pwd`, so that you see what your working directory is (maybe your Python program depends on it). BTW, the `set` command is described in the bash man-page in the section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_.

Comment: @user1934428  Done! I have posted the trace output above in the question

Comment: So we see that the Python program is running. Now you have to debug this. BTW, I would remove the `exec`. While it should not harm, deleting it would ensure that you also see whether your Python program terminates. BTW, my guess is that the Subprocess.call fails. You invoke `python` without having set a PATH. Hence I would provide the absolute path to the python executable in subprocess.call.

Comment: @user1934428 You mean `subprocess.run(["/root/pipedrive_CRM/venv/bin/python", program])` venv python path?

Comment: This would be my first try. Of course I would also populate the Python program with more print statements, so that you see what is going on. And I would evaluate the return value of subprocess.call, so that you know whether or not (from the Python viewpoint) it succeeded.

Comment: BTW (since I'm not really a Python guy): What is the difference between `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.call`?

Comment: subprocess. call() is to be used when you need to execute a command and have it wait until the command has fully completed. subprocess. run() should be used when more control is needed such as handling the commands stderr and stdout, capturing output and being able to define the command execution timeout.

Comment: @user1934428 I tried defining the absolute path but same results scripts getting run manuallay when I run `./cron.sh` but when I try to run via crontab it only generates pid file scripts not running.

Comment: Well, then go on with my debugging suggestions. You don't have to report back every interim result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mkdir` atomic/semaphore trick.

```
#! /bin/bash
if mkdir $HOME/foo 2> /dev/null
then
    echo $$ > $HOME/foo/pid
    echo We are running.
    sleep 2
    rm -rf $HOME/foo
else
    echo Error, process $(cat $HOME/foo/pid) already running.
    echo If process chrashed run: kill $(cat $HOME/foo/pid) \; rm -rf \$HOME/foo
fi
```

The trick is to use a directory not a file. Two process can't create a directory at the same time and get successful result at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Always redirect *all* output of your cron-jobs so you can see what happened at runtime (otherwise any output would be e-mailed to root). I always add `myscript > myscript.cron.log 2>&1` e.g.:

```
52 21 * * * /root/pipedrive_CRM/cron.sh > /root/pipedrive_CRM/cron.sh.cron.log 2>&1
```

You need to have more details on what's going wrong. It could be that you have to activate the Python virtual environment:

```
source /root/pipedrive_CRM/venv/bin/activate
```

prior to running the Python script and/or add directories to the $PATH in your cron.sh script for example.